# Group not listed in groups command

Tags: group

On Ubuntu 22.04, I've installed `docker`, added myself to the `docker` group with `sudo usermod -a -G docker user`, and logged out/in.

However, I still get "permission denied" errors when running `docker` commands.  In `/etc/group`, I see

```
docker:x:133:user
```

but `docker` doesn't show up when I run `groups`.

Comment: Does the command `newgrp docker` fix the issue? This should log one into a new group without needing the logout/back in cycle.

Comment: Yeah, that works.

Comment: If you logged out from your desktop environment, it’s possible you picked your systemd user session back up when you logged in again, so your groups didn’t change.

Comment: @StephenKitt, how would I confirm/fix this?

Comment: You could look at the start time of your user session: `systemctl status --user`, and look for “Since:” near the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jumping on what @Stephen-Kitt said, `systemctl status --user` confirmed that after logging out and back in picked up my old session. Even after a reboot!

I read somewhere rebooting from the terminal will start a new user session and thereby picking up your new groups.

`sudo reboot now` fixed it for me.

`groups` then finally had the `docker` group in for me in a new terminal session.